# Cocoapods Installation

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Dears,

I have this case I am trying to make this Control work:

https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker

Its a image picker that needs to be installed using Cocoapods. I know its a newbie question.

But i downloaded the Installed cocoapods and then went to my example folder and ran the "pod install" and it was successfull:

"Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 3 total pods installed."

So everything should be great. But when i open the project and try to run it, This error occurs:

"No such module 'BSImagePicker'"

I cant get how things work here. Is there is any further steps should i do after "pod install" I am new for cocoapods. Maybe something i missed.

Your support is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Did you open the workspace or the project file? Open the workspace and then try to do a full build. When I see this error usually a full build makes it go away.

Comment: Also did you tell Cocoapods to `use_frameworks!`? If not then you will need to add the library to your bridging header instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points:

1. Make sure your pod file has `use_frameworks!` line uncommented. if not, uncomment and reinstall pods.
2. Make sure you have opened the workspace, not the project file. Clean (`Cmd+Shift+K`) and Build (`Cmd+B`).
3. In the code where you want to use the BSImagePicker, make sure you import it i.e. `import BSImagePicker`

I just tried it and it works fine, here's what the `Podfile` looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'ExampleApp' do
    pod "BSImagePicker", "~> 2.2"
end

target 'ExampleAppTests' do

end

target 'ExampleAppUITests' do

end
```

Comment: I am trying to install this pod and it's taking suspiciously long time on `Installing BSImagePicker (2.2.0) line`.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I have another question, It would be great if you can support me in it. Is there is a way i can make this work without cocoapods ?

Comment: Yes, copying all the files in _Pods_ directory to your project should make it work, but why don't you want to use Pods may I ask? Unless you are using some other tool e.g. `Carthage`, I'd recommend you stick with Pods, it makes dependency management very easy.

Comment: just because this is a project that was not built from start on cocoapods and i dont know, if i start using it now it will change the project structure "the workspace" and the pod folder. Do you think i should use it anyways ?

Comment: yes, use it anyway, it shouldn't do much harm since it's not changing your project a lot (except adding entries that make the modules in Pods project available to it). Once you have used it for a month or so, there'll be no turning back I tell you. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your support :)

Comment: I have some problem it produce some error in settings, cameracell, selection class  when install by pods